# How to use bitcoin testnet wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, faucets

I have a simple use case.

> I want to send some testnet coins to my testnet wallet and be able to
>   see it in bitcoin-core in testnet mode

What I did so far: 1. Go to File-->Receiving address. Setup a new reciving address here
2. Go to website providing free testnet coins and send it the address that I set in step 1.
3. Wait until the transaction is confirmed.

Questions:
I expect to see the above transactions in the bitcoin UI. Eg. If I click on 'Overview' button, I expect to see those testnet bitcoins. Similarly, under 'Transactions', I see nothing. Could somebody point out what is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the transaction ID and/or receiving address you used?  Has Bitcoin Core finished synchronizing?  You are running it in testnet mode?

Comment: Thnx for checking. I did transaction more than 12 hours ago. Aahh! But I see your point, my Bitcoin core is yet far behind and thus may have not seen the transaction. Let me wait for it to finish synchronizing.

Comment: Yes, you won't see it until synchronization is finished.  I think that's the issue.  If so, could you either delete this question, or else post your own answer and accept it (click the check mark)?  This site tends to get quite cluttered by unanswered questions.

Comment: (I see you have a few other questions with answers that you haven't accepted - it would be good to either do that, or else leave a comment explaining why it doesn't resolve your issue.  The site will continually bump questions whose answers aren't upvoted or accepted.)

Comment: Thanks Nate. Yeah, I am bit of newbie on stack exchange. I see your point. I will leave this question as I think it would be helpful to somebody starting afresh with bitcoin testnet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nate, the quite possible reason is that since my bitcoin core is still synchronizing, it would not have seen the transaction.

Will await for this to complete. Thanks again, Nate!